# Doxygen and Matlab

Tags: matlab, doxygen

i am trying to use Doxygen to make the documentation for my matlab code, so in the log the following warning is shown:
"C:\DoxygenMatlab\m2cpp" it doesnt recognise like a in or out command, program or file for the executable.
Can somebody help me?
Thanks
Sonsoles

Comment: Never tried to use doxygen, but have you seen this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?term=doxygen

Comment: You may also consider `Sphinx`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610241/doxygen-and-matlab